# host own pacman repo with apache web server

Tags: arch-linux, apache-http-server, repository

I want to host my own ArchLinux pacman repository for my own packages. I already found out, I can simply create a repo by just using `repo-add` and if I upload the generated `foo.db.tar.gz` and its symlink to my webserver, I can access this repo by just adding the following lines to my `/etc/pacman.conf`

```
[foo]
Server = http://example.com/foo/
```

But when I now add another package to the repo and again upload the `foo.db.tar.gz` to the web server, then run `pacman -Syy` and try to install the new package with `pacman -S bar`, the package can't be found.

Also, if I just run `pacman -Sy`, pacman tells me, there are no changes for my own repo.

So, what is wrong with my configuration? I think my apache has to be configured in a special way, but I can't find any hint on the web. Any idea?

*Note: the apache web server runs on a ubuntu linux server*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fault. For any reason the `foo.db` file (which is a symlink generated by `repo-add` and links to `foo.db.tar.gz`) was copied as regular file and not as a symlink. So, after updating `foo.db.tar.gz` on the server I still had the old tar.gz on the server, called `foo.db`.

So I removed `foo.db` and replaced it with a symlink and everything's fine now.